# pg_insert fails telling table doesn't exists

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$db=pg_connect(...) or die("could not connect\n");
$r=pg_query($db,'drop table if exists vivatransaction;');
$r=pg_query($db,'create table vivatransaction(rowid integer primary key);');
$a=['rowid'=>10];
$r=pg_insert($db,'vivatransaction',$a);
```

The error I get is: pg_insert(): Table 'vivatransaction' doesn't exists in xxx.php on line ...

Comment: `pg_query()` returns false on failure. You're not checking to verify that the `create table` statement worked.

Comment: The table has indeed been created and exists.

Comment: I also put some sleep(5) in order to delay the process just in case the table creation delays, same result !

Comment: Maybe you need fully qualified names, issue a `show search_path;` from php.

Comment: Your code has no errors, execute after your connection `$r=pg_query($db,'show search_path;');    $row=pg_fetch_assoc($r); echo $row['search_path']??'No data';` to findout in what schema are being executed those instructions.